# Oracle DB Instance on oracle cloud free tier disappeared

Tags: oracle, cloud, infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have created an oracle free tier account a few months back and tried to log in one day and my db instance along with apex and all my work disappeared. I don't know how this happened and why my instance disappeared on the oracle cloud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for Always Free Autonomous Databases: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/autonomous-always-free.html#GUID-03F9F3E8-8A98-4792-AB9C-F0BACF02DC3E

> Persistently inactive Always Free Autonomous Databases are detected
> and handled as follows:
>
> - After being inactive for 7 days, the database will be stopped automatically, preserving its stored data. Inactivity measurements
>   leading up to 7 days are based on database connections. Successfully
>   making a SQL*Net or HTTPS connection resets these measurements to
>   zero.
> - **A database that is automatically or manually stopped and stays inactive for 90 days, cumulative, may be reclaimed and permanently**
>   deleted.

If it has been more than 90 days since you last used your database, it is gone.

Note: Oracle would have sent you multiple e-mail warnings before doing this.

Comment: I was literally just using the database and doing work on my apex application and then it just stopped working. When I went and checked my instance I couldn't find it.  Approximately 10 minutes ago the database was working fine.

Comment: Also, i use the database almost every week

Comment: @BasudevSingh - shouldn't you be asking Oracle about this then?

Comment: they are taking too long to respond, and I need this urgently. I found an old backup of my files so I will just create an instance and run it back

Comment: @BasudevSingh that is very odd!

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with my free tier account 144.24.112.30 ubuntu instance. It seems that their region and tenancies are crashing, and their engineers don't have mechanism to track sudden losses. Oracle is relatively new in cloud niche, so it is expected, compared to successful giants like aws and google cloud. At least disappearing instance, having live website is not exptected